# How to make scroller in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I want to make scroller like given here: http://www.shopping.com/xPC-Kettler-Kettler-Vito-Xl~linkin_id-8051267

in jQuery. Its in dojo I think. Please give me link of scroller like this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine there are lots of different plugins for a jQuery scroller, heres one:

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/scrollable-jquery-plugin-to-scroll-content/

and the demo of it working:

http://www.flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable.html

hope this helps! :)

Comment: I am using the same scroller for my application, but next & prev buttons work when I click on them, I want the same thing when I mouseover on next and prev buttons, as done in the link I have given.

Answer (score 1):

[This one perhaps](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) (jcarousel)

Edit: jCarousel doesn't support mouseovers though

Comment: True, but if you take a look at the actual widget's structure I think it'd be quite easy to move/copy the onclick handler to the mouseover.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel like rolling your own then I have a basic recipe for building this kind of carousel in an answer to [jCarousel with unknown content width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397184/jcarousel-with-unknown-content-width#408404).